# Page Not Displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, semantic-ui

I am stuck on this problem for days and the solutions that I find on the web are not helpful.
My routes are not working properly. The URI is updating, but the appropriate pages are not displaying according to the path.
When I refresh the browser, only then, the appropriate page comes through. Otherwise, only the home page is displayed, even when the path changes.

I will  do my best to exhaust the codes here:

**package.json**

```
...
"history": "^5.3.0",
"node-sass": "^8.0.0",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
...
```

**AppRoutes.js**

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
...

const AppRoutes = () => {
    const routes = useRoutes([
        { path: PATH.home, element: <page.Home /> },
        { path: PATH.defect, element: <page.Defect /> },
        { path: PATH.other, element: <page.Other /> },
        { path: PATH.allRoutes, element: <page.Home /> }
    ]);

    return routes;
}
```

**Navbar.js**

```
...
import history from '../../utils/BrowserHistory';
...

/**
 * I am using semantic UI menu
 * Here I push the path for a browser route change
 */
handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => {
        this.setState({ activeItem: name });

        switch (name) {
            case APP_CONST.home:  
                history.push(PATH.home);
                break;
            case APP_CONST.defect:
                history.push(PATH.defect);
                break;
            case APP_CONST.other:
                history.push(PATH.other);
                break;
            default:
                history.push(PATH.home);
                break;
        }
    }
...

render() {
        const { activeItem } = this.state;

        return (
            <Fragment>
                {
                    this.state.width <= NUMBER.mobileScreenSize ?
                        <MobileNav
                            onToggle={this.handleToggle}
                            visible={this.state.visible}
                            onPusherClick={this.handlePusher}
                            item={activeItem}
                            handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick}
                        >
                            <NavBarChildren>{this.props.children}</NavBarChildren>
                        </MobileNav> :
                        <DesktopNav item={activeItem} handleItemClick={this.handleItemClick}>
                            <NavBarChildren>{this.props.children}</NavBarChildren>
                        </DesktopNav>
                }
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const NavBarChildren = props => (
    <Container>{props.children}</Container>
);
```

**DesktopNav.js**

```
export const DesktopNav = props => {

    const { item, handleItemClick, children } = props;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Menu fixed='top' pointing secondary>
                <Menu.Menu>
                    <MenuItems item={item} handleItemClick={handleItemClick} />
                </Menu.Menu>
            </Menu>
            <div className='desktop-menu-items'>{children}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

**App.js**

```
imports ...

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationBar>
      <AppRoutes />
    </NavigationBar>
  )
}
```

**index.js**

```
...
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './utils/BrowserHistory';
...

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**Please assist, thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`BrowserRouter`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L282-L286) doesn't consume a `history` prop. The `BrowserRouter` maintains its own internal `history` reference, and so isn't aware of the URL changes your custom `history` object makes.

If you are effecting navigation actions from the custom `history` object in that `Navbar` component instead of using `Link` components then you'll need to use a router that can take the custom `history` object so it can synchronize the routes it manages with the URL changes the `history` object effects.

You can import the [`HistoryRouter`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L361-L390), which *does* consume a `history` prop.

Example:

```
...
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './utils/BrowserHistory';
...

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <HistoryRouter history={history}>
    <App />
  </HistoryRouter>
);
```